# How can I set my imageviews to fill linearlayout with equal spacing?

Tags: android-layout

I have four image icons that I need to display with Imagebutton or Imageview. The problem is when I use the following code, they all are aligned left leaving an empty space to the right.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/sale"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/shirt"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/women"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/technology"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I get them equally distributed on the linearlayout so that they fill the whole width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to fix the issue. It seems I was needed to use `android:layout_width"fill_parent"` instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content".` I tried this after @grwww suggested `android:layout_gravity="fill"` which was not the needed attribute. Then I got to learn about `fill_parent`